# Failure when running deployNodes

Tags: corda

Sporadically, I get the following error message from running the Corda `deployNodes` task:

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':deployNodes'.
> classLoader.getResourceAsStream(storeResourceName) must not be null
```

How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

This issue is caused by a zombie Java process. Try killing any Java processes and trying again.